# "npx prisma migrate dev" fails -> Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`3306`

Tags: mysql, prisma, next.js13

I'm not able to create migrations in prisma.

Command:

```
npx prisma migrate dev
```

Error:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MySQL database "nextapp123" at "localhost:3306"

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`3306`.
```

My basic `schema.prisma` file:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email     String  @unique
  name      String
  followers Int     @default(0)
  isActive  Boolean @default(true)
}
```

`.env` file

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:Sqlnotmy1@localhost:3306/nextapp123"
```

There's a bunch of things I've already tried.

**9).**
I re-edited and kept the result of my latest debugging attempt at the top, before other points below:

[image]

I could establish the connection and run migration with PlanetScale's hosted MySQL Database online but the same migration (or `db push`) fails locally with the same error:

[image]

**I'm badly stuck here for close to a week now which has wasted a lot of time.**

**8).**
Using **DBeaver** as well as **DataGrip** (JetBrains) IDEs, I'm successfully able to connect to my MySQL Server 8.2 instance at localhost:3306.

[image: DataGrip connection status]

This confirms that MySQL server instance is up locally despite which it's not able to connect to Prisma.

**Can this be a version non-compatibility issue between Prisma and MySQL Server?**

Prisma: 5.2.2 , My SQL: 8.2

============================

**1).**
Checked MySQL Server status:

[image: Checking if server is up and running]

**2).**
Checked whether server is listening at port: 3306

[image: 3306 port status]

**3).**
Additional check at port 3306

[image: 3306 port status]

**4).**
Made sure the MySQL Server 8.2 Configurator is set up correctly.
I have the complete Config log file.
The last line of the config file states:

[image: MySQL Server 8.2 - Config file]

**5).**
Experimented by canceling the check box just to see if Firewall is doing some mess up

[image: MySQL Server 8.2 configurator wizard]

**6).**
Checked MySQL82 service is running in Windows Services app and it does show running.
[image: Windows Service app]

**7).**
I could not find any Config file with the name `my.ini` in the folder where MySQL Server 8.2 is installed locally.
So, I created one in Notepad (admin privilege) and saved there.

[image: my.ini config file]

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port = 3306
```

======================

That's all i could do to debug.

I'm new to Next.js/Prisma/MySQL development.

I'm stuck at this error for close to **3 days now** and tried everything with debugging that I could find online.

Read some of the previous similar questions (like the one below) on the forum but could not find an answer to my query.

(Question)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653041/prisma-error-p1001-cant-reach-database-server-at-localhost3306]

So, thought of posting a fresh question.

I'm sorry if it's repetitive.

I cannot proceed until I'm able to create migrations.

It has already wasted 3 days of mine.

Community, please help.

Thank you

Comment: Can some one at least provide me with some pointers to look into other debugging options?

Comment: Anyone out there who can provide me with any pointers whatsoever to at least proceed with further debugging?

Comment: Anyone, any pointers, anything if you feel (even remotely) that can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add relationMode = "prisma" to schema.prisma file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D66gp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdWy8.png)

Comment: Thanks @starhasi for the reply.
I actually started using a different SQL management service provider's solution and it worked perfectly.
However, I'll soon try this fix as well to see the outcome.